# AR model estimated with Yule-Walker equation is poor

Tags: time-series, estimation, autoregressive

Hello :) I am an undergraudate student studying time series analysis as a way to kill time during the Covid-19 self-quarantine. I write this to ask you, what could be the possible reasons behind my poor time series model.

I have a time series data $x_t$ with clear positive trend, with a (humble) sample size $T=24$. I am estimating an AR(2) model $$x_t = \delta + \alpha_1 x_{t-1}+ \alpha_2 x_{t-2} + u_t,$$
where $\delta$ is a constant and $u_t$ is a pure random process.

With some method that will be explained below, I obtained estimates for $\delta$ and $\alpha$s, and made forecasts for $T+1, T+2, ...$ using the conditional expectation $ E[x_{T+\tau}|x_T, x_{T-1},...] $, where $ \tau \in \mathbb{N} $. Specifically, I obtained the forecasts by recursively solving the difference equation $$x_{T+\tau} = \delta + \alpha_1 x_{T+\tau-1} + \alpha_2 x_{T+\tau-2} $$ with the initial conditions $ x_{T+1} $ and $x_{T+2}$ obtained from the current data set.

Now I demonstrate that my estimates for the parameters, and therefore the forecasts, are poor.
[image: Blue line denotes the data set, red line denotes the forecast from the AR(2) model]
Clearly, there is something wrong with the parameters, as the forecast is flowing into the opposite direction.

I suspect the reason lies behind the method of estimation I used. First, here is how I estimated the alphas. Under the ergodicity assumption, I used the estimators for a stationary process $$ \hat{\mu} = \frac{1}{T} \sum x_t, \quad \hat{\rho_\tau} = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^{T-\tau}(x_t - \hat{\mu})(x_{t+\tau}-\hat{\mu})}{\sum(x_t - \hat{\mu})^2} $$
for the mean and autocorrelations of the process. Using the estimated autocorrelations, I used the Yule-Walker equation $$ \begin{pmatrix} \hat{\rho_1} \\ \hat{\rho_2} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1& \hat{\rho_1} \\ \hat{\rho_1}& 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \alpha_1 \\ \alpha_2 \end{pmatrix} $$
to determine the unknown alphas.  For the $\delta$ I used the relationship $$ E(x_t) = \mu = \frac{\delta}{1-\alpha_1 - \alpha_2} \rightarrow \delta \approx \hat{\mu} \times (1-\alpha_1 - \alpha_2) $$ which follows from the definition of the AR(2) process.

Here are my questions:

1. Is there something wrong with my approach here?
2. If there is nothing wrong with my approach, why are my estimates much poorer than the OLS
   estimates? (I ran the OLS and the forecast is much better.)

Thank you for reading my poorly versed question. From this question I hope to better understand how to estimate AR(2) models. I wish everyone stay healthy during this pandemic.

Comment: "clear positive trend..."---therein lies your problem. You're fitting stationary model to clearly non-stationary data. What is in your OLS regression, does it include a time trend?